# Unable to push an edited .py file - takes too long in 'writing objects'

Tags: python, git

I've modified my `.py` (python file) with some lines, the I've commited the changes and added them. When I push to the `origin master` it takes a long time, it uploads to over `100MB` in "Writing Objects", and then it fails to push it.

Why doesn't it just push the added file which contains some minor changes in my code which should weight like `2-3KB` max. why this happens?

```
Pushing to https://github.com/@MyUsername/@MyGitRep.git
Counting objects: 10, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
POST git-receive-pack (chunked)
Writing objects:  90% (9/10), 7.33 MiB | 252.00 KiB/s
```

Trying using `git-gc`, `git push --verbose origin master`

Comment: You didn't show the add and commit steps. Did you accidentally add a whole bunch of other files by any chance?

Comment: Is altering the python file _really_ the only thing in your commit? You didn't accidentally add some images, or a bunch of .pyc files, or anything?

Comment: You could also show your .gitignore. you shouldn't really push any python binaries as they may change from system to system. add `*.pyc`, `__pycache__` , `'build/`', `.mypy_cache/` to your gitignore

Comment: You have probably some huge files in the files hiarchy that must not be added to the repository. Find them and ignore them. The best way to add and commit is to

Comment: Exactly what @d_kennetz said, also maybe show us what `git status` shows you, you might have some build files/ temp junk files that it is pushing

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yeah that's what happened. I just deleted the whole rep. cloned it again, and did the commit(s) from scratch again, which took additional few minutes. I need to be more careful when doing this in order not to push unnecessary files. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just deleted the whole rep. cloned it again, and did the commit(s) from scratch again, which took additional few minutes. I need to be more careful when commiting in order not to push unnecessary files. Thanks everyone!